# Layout issue in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a searchbar below the Action bar. It should be displayed above the viewpager title strip. But the view pager title strip is overlapping in this. Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong here?

here is my layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/search_edit_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-5dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/searchbar_bg"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

     <Button 
            android:id="@+id/search_go_btn"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dip"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_src_text"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5.0"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textColor="@color/white"

            android:hint="Search Products or Stores"
            android:singleLine="true" >
            <requestFocus/>
            </EditText>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/search_voice_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     tools:context=".HomeActivity">

   <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#CCCC99"       
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:paddingTop="50dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" >   
    </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

I have tried splitting searchbar into a separate linearlayout. It doesn't work well then also.

Comment: Trying out now with RelativeLayout. But still facing overlapping issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `android:orientation="vertical"` to the top LinearLayout. I think horizontal is the default, and how I understand you want them underneath each other.